# How to use apex-d3-organization-chart plugin

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

I want to create an organization chart with apex-d3-organization-chart plugin.
I added this plugin, then I created a page and inserted a region and changed that to this plugin.
In the source section of that region has written this code:

```
SELECT
       /* positive number id of the element (should start with 1 or higher) */
       ROWNUM                          AS ID,
       /* positive number id of the parent (top parent should be 0) */
       CASE
         WHEN ROWNUM <= 1 THEN 0
         WHEN ROWNUM <= 4 THEN 1
         ELSE ROUND(ROWNUM / 4)
       END                             AS PARENT_ID,
       /* name of the item */
       'Item '
       || ROWNUM                       AS NAME,
       /* tooltip for the item */
       'This is item '
       || ROWNUM                       AS TOOLTIP,
       /* link of the item (is only used when is leaf) */
       'https://github.com/RonnyWeiss' AS LINK,
       /* color of the item */
       DECODE(ROWNUM, 1, 'rgba(192,0,15,1)', NULL) AS COLOR
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 30
```

Now I want to change that and use my table.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First copy that query in SQL command and run that. Now you can see a table with some fields. Now write a select query that has fields exactly like the source query.
Something like that:

```
    SELECT 
    ID,
    PARENT_ID,
    TITLE as NAME,
    CASE WHEN 
    PARENT_ID=0 THEN 'rgba(192,0,15,1)'
    ELSE 'rgba(0,0,250,1)'
    END as COLOR
    FROM TLX_USER_ROLE
    ORDER BY PARENT_ID asc
```